# Function not working in python

Tags: python, function

Newbie in programming. Trying to self-teach using Head First Programming book.
I can not get this following code to work;

```
            def make_smoothie():
                juice = input("What juice would you like?")
                fruit = input("Ok- and how about the fruit?")
                print "Thanks. Lets go!"
                print "Crushing ice..."
                print "Blending the %d" % fruit
                print "Now adding in the %d juice" %juice
                print "Finished! There's your %d and %d smoothie" %(fruit, juice)


            print ("Welcome to smoothie")
            another ="Y"
            while another=="Y":
                make_smoothie()
                another = input ("How about another (Y/N)?")
```

Keep getting the error that the input for juice or fruit is not defined

Comment: Try replacing the instances of `%d` with `%s`

Comment: Same error, input for juice is not defined.

Comment: see my answer ... its cause that code is meant for python3 but you are using python 2 ... and the user input methods are a little difference

Comment: Done! Worked. Thanks heaps

Comment: Please mark at least one answer as accepted so person gets credit and so browswer like me know that you aoready have answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a guess ... if you are using python 2 then use `raw_input` instead of `input` ... (in python 2 `input` will try to evaluate the users input to a python object (integer or variable name, etc) ... `raw_input` will return the user input as a string)

consider

```
>>> apple = 555
>>> print input("Enter Fruit:")
Enter Fruit:apple
555 #returns the value of the variable apple ... if that does not exist you get an error
>>> print raw_input("Enter Fruit:")
Enter Fruit:apple
apple #returns the string "apple"
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me and I am using Python 2.x. Are you providing numbers for juice and fruit because you use %d for text formatting?

```
oltjano@baby:~/Desktop/unveil/tests$ python juice.py 
Welcome to smoothie
How about another (Y/N)?"Y"
What juice would you like?1
Ok- and how about the fruit?2
Thanks. Lets go!
Crushing ice...
Blending the 2
Now adding in the 1 juice
Finished! There's your 2 and 1 smoothie
How about another (Y/N)?
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that even if he fixes input it will still break on his format string